# Fastest method to create HTML elements?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

Consider this example code:

```
function appendText()
{
    var txt1="<p>Text.</p>";               // Create element with HTML 

    var txt2=$("<p></p>").text("Text.");   // Create with jQuery

    var txt3=document.createElement("p");  // Create with DOM
    txt3.innerHTML="Text.";

    $("p").append(txt1,txt2,txt3);         // Append the new elements
}
```

In above code I've created paragraphs using three different techniques. I want to know which one is faster & more efficient in phonegap?

Comment: Aside from #2 which is rather inefficient, I think the margin between #1 and #3 will be very small; in real-life code, I'd use whichever is the clearest. In this circumstance, that would be #1.

Comment: @dystroy no i just want to know which approach is right & more faster for execution

Comment: You might want to try http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Just a note: #1 is also creating element with jQuery but with append() function.

Comment: The performance of doing this once is irrelevant. It will matter when you do this lots of times and then an at the very least equally important factor is how you manage that.

Comment: @Joonas thanks for link you provide, this will help me a lot in future

Comment: Is the `.append()` line also part of the question btw? It didn't seem like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var txt1="<p>Text.</p>";               // Create element with HTML 
// actually: $('<p>Text.</p>');
```

In this case, jQuery will create a `<div>` element, then set its `.innerHTML` property to the HTML string you've passed. This is not particularly fast.

```
var txt2=$("<p></p>").text("Text.");   // Create with jQuery
```

This is much faster, because jQuery is optimized to map this straight to `createElement()` and you're using `.text()` so no additional parsing is required.

```
var txt3=document.createElement("p");  // Create with DOM
txt3.innerHTML="Text.";
```

This sidesteps some parts of the two approaches and *should* be faster, but isn't because you're using `.innerHTML` which has to get parsed first.

The fastest would be this:

```
var txt4 = document.createElement('p');
txt4.textContent = 'Text.';
```

[**Proof**](http://jsperf.com/create-elements-jq-vs-native)

Note that when I say fast, it's based on the results of this particular test case; normally you wouldn't get to a point where this would matter. Also, the native version is so much faster that a separate test would have to be done to get more accurate results for the other test cases :)

Answer (score -1):

The fastest among these is :

```
  var txt3=document.createElement("p");  // Create with DOM
  txt3.innerHTML="Text.";
```

Because when you use JQuery to append any element, it traverses through the entire DOM to search for the particular ID you want to append , While using native JS , it will traverse till it finds the 1st occurance of the element where you want to append.

EG:

```
  <div id="a">
      <div id="b">
           <div id="c"></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Suppose you want to append some text in "b", JQuery will traverse till "c" while native JS will traverse only till "b" [the first instance of that ID]

Comment: That's actually not the fastest, because even `$(<p /'>).text('Text.')` is faster than that; reason being that the `.innerHTML` propery is slower (and usually wrong for adding text anyway). Not sure what the second part of your answer is about.